# How to guarantee atomic batch insert with pure Hibernate inside @Transactional method in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, atomic, rollback

To simplify my scenario I would give the following example:

I'm using a Spring Boot application with spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true property.

Inside a java method marked with @Transactional annotation I want to perform a batch insert of a few thousand records with pure hibernate. The batch insert is performed by a separate method which is called by the main method with @Transactional. I'm doing it like that:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomeStuff() {
......
insertRecords(records, session);
......
}


private void insertRecords(final List<Record> records, final Session session) {
  int counter = 0;
  int batchSize = 50;
  for(Record r: records){
    session.save(r);

    counter ++;

    if(counter > 0 && counter % batchSize == 0){
       session.flush(); 
       session.clear();
    }

    }
}
```

The problem is that I want the operation to be atomic and if one of the batch inserts, fails everything to be rolled back. I know @Transactional anotation will guarantee rollback automatically for RunTimeException or Error. Does this mean that if one of the batches fails @Transactional will cover the rollback or I should surround the for cycle with try/catch block and throw a checked exception and use the rollbackFor propery of @Transactional? I'm not sure if the exceptions thrown during batch failure are checked or unchecked.

Another important question is does in this scenario hibernate commit every batch automatically in case of successfull insert? This would mean that if one batch fails I wouldn't be able to rollback the already committed once which breaks the atomicity.

In addition, I don't want to manage the commits manually and want to handle this to the transactional context provided by Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. By default , `@Transactional` will only rollback for `RuntimeException` and `Error` but not for checked exception. That means if you want to also rollback the checked exception , you have to catch all the checked exception and re-throw it as the `RuntimeException` or simply use `rollbackFor` setting in `@Transactional`.

> I'm not sure if the exceptions thrown during batch failure are checked
>   or unchecked.

The java compiler will help to check it.If some of the inner methods throw checked exception ,it requires you must handle it which you can neither catch it or specify to throw this checked exception in the method declaration. The codes cannot be compiled if you do not do so.

That means if your codes can compile, no checked exception is thrown from the inner methods and you can simply stick to the current settings. On the other hands, if some checked exception are thrown from the inner methods , you can choose to catch it and re-throw it as `RuntimeException` :

```
@Transactional
public void doSomeStuff()  {
    try{

    }catch(Exception ex){
      throw new RuntimeException("something goes wrong.." ,ex);
    }
}
```

or configure `rollbackFor`

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
public void doSomeStuff() throws Exception{

}
```

Also , please note that `session.flush()` is not the same as committing transaction, so your codes will not commit for every batch. Instead, transaction will commit after the method marked with @Transactional return successfully which in your case is the returned of `doSomeStuff()` when all the records are inserted.

The point of `flush()` is for the subsequent `session.clear()` which clear the memory from the session such that it will not cause the JVM to run out of memory if you insert a lot of records.

Comment: You're right. The code compiles so I believe every exception produced by a batch operation is RunTimeException and will be automatically covered by @Transactional for performing rollback. I know that session.flush() is not the same as commit but my point about the commit was different. I think I've read that when you use the property 'spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true' the successful batches are commited automatically which got me confused but it might be that I misunderstood the article or there was a mistake in it.

Comment: `hibernate.order_inserts` has nothing to do with transaction .It is for fine tuning the performance.

Comment: I see. Btw, I have additional question. I am using a hbm.xml for describing the entity and a org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator for the ID. I want to use the ids returned by the save method, however I receive the same ID for a given batch chunk. After I execute flush then a new ID is generated. So if the batch size is 50 for 100 records in stead of inserting 100 I insert 2. Do you know how to make the sequence generate a new ID after every save execution? I am using increment size bigger than 1 both in the xml and DB and a pooled optimizer.

Comment: i have no clue now , does the "increment" step configured in hbm.xml match with the increment step in corresponding database sequence ? it is better to ask a new question